# How do I use my phone as a WiFi hotspot without using my data connection?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I know it sounds strange, but what I want to do is use my phone as a WiFi router to create a private LAN that doesn't use my data connection.  Basically, I'm at a hotel and need to do some testing using a HHC that is designed to connect to a LAN and talk to a database over that LAN; I'm hosting SQL Server on my laptop, but I'm not comfortable connecting my customer's HHC to the hotel's network in such a way that I can test.  I know that I can create and host a wireless LAN from my phone, but the option is disabled when I have data turned off.

I'm using a Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0

Comment: Have you tried turning on the hotspot (with the data on) and then turn the mobile data off after the hotspot is turned on. This should work for you.

Answer (score -2):

1. Turn off your mobile data. 2. Turn on your mobile hotspot.

Comment: Normal Human, what phone are you using? The instructions I gave will work on a Note 3, which is the phone used in the original post.

Comment: Tried this every way I could think of (turned data off, turned on airplane mode, removed sim) and every time the option to turn on hotspot is disabled.

Comment: @jvance Airplane mode must not be enabled because that kills all connections including hotspot (WiFi). Wifi must be on. Only mobile data must be disabled.

Comment: My earlier comment was unclear.  I tried disabling data using the three methods listed individually, not in combination.